# 64Bit and Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: software-installation, 64-bit

My new RPi4 arrived yesterday, and I'm trying out the 64bit OS. Most of it has been fine. As a large program to try out the 64 bit space Common LISP in its SBCL implementation installed and ran fine with the McClim GUI package as a trial. However, Wolfram Mathematica will not install (and I've posted it to  [the GitHub site](https://github.com/raspberrypi/Raspberry-Pi-OS-64bit/issues/33)) so in case anyone can shed light on what the problem is I'd be grateful.

I have installed Java openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14 and Fortran but that installed libgfortran5:armhf

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wolfram-engine:armhf : Depends: oracle-java7-jdk:armhf but it is not installable or
                                 oracle-java8-jdk:armhf but it is not installable or
                                 openjdk-11-jdk:armhf but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libssl1.0.2:armhf but it is not installable
                        Depends: liboauth0:armhf but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgfortran3:armhf but it is not installable
```

Comment: This has probably to do with the fact that the 64bit OS is rather new and not all packages have catched up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today 12th September 2020 (at least) Wolfram Mathematica 12.1 now installs on 64bit Raspbian OS, and seems nicely responsive.

Comment: Instructions? Links?

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2023, the latest Raspberry Pi version of Wolfram Mathematica 13.2.1 is 64-bit.

It may be installed as usual

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wolfram-engine
```

Note it requires Raspberry Pi OS based on Debian 11 (bullseye).